Authenticate User with conditions in Laravel 11 Sanctum
I am writing a CRUD controller which will only write to the DB if $user->user_type!=5 . I am using $user = auth()->user(); to authenticate the user. My current code needs an if statement with the above condition wrapping the entire working of the function and I was wondering if there was a better way.
I checked the docs for Laravel, but I feel the Sanctum Documentation to be underwhelming in general. While I'm okay with the if statement, I was thinking if Laravel had a conditioned validation that would make the code more compact.

How a single if-else makes a code non-compact, even when its mandatory?

You could write an middleware to handle the request, or if it's only for specific controllers you can use Requests.
See: https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/middleware#defining-middleware and https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/validation#authorizing-form-requests

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Just add a guard before the actual code instead of nesting the main code inside an if condition.
if($user->user_type === 5) return response(); // or something else

// Insert into DB

